# On the iPad, is there a way to email a link to a mapped set of directions?

Tags: google-maps

Now that I have the directions from A to B, I want to mail them to a contact, ideally as a Google Map link.  I see no way to do so within the iPad Maps application, but maybe I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to email a link to something you have got to inside a native iOS app, in your case, a set of instructions. I believe however that you can email a set of instructions as a link from the google maps website, which you can access in safari. Hope this helps in some form.

Answer (score 2):

I want to e-mail a link to a set of Google map directions from my iPad.  Go to Google maps via safari, and make sure you've got the 'classic' view as this has the print option on it.  Find your route, then press the 'print' option and then, on the iPad you've got the 'mail this link' option which sends a link to that printed page of directions.